# reuse one field value to other field using group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I have following query in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(field1, field2, field3, field4......)
SELECT  field1, field2, 
        function_name(field3,'2012-01-01'), 
        function_name(field3,'2012-01-01')/field1..... 
from table_name2 group by field1, field2;
```

My question is the above query is working fine but as I am using function_name(field3,'2012-01-01') in multiple time so its taking too long time to execute. Now I want i will execute once function_name(field3,'2012-01-01') and will use for field3 and as well as field4. I will not call again function_name for field4 as already I have executed it for field filed3.

So the query should be like this

```
INSERT INTO table_name(field1, field2, field3,field4......)
SELECT  field1, field2, 
         @res:=function_name(field3,'2012-01-01'), 
        @res/field1..... 
 from table_name2 
 group by field1, field2;
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`INSERT INTO table_name(field1, field2, field3, field4......) SELECT field1, field2, function_name(field3,'2012-01-01') as @res, @res/field1..... from table_name2 group by field1, field2;`

Comment: The above query throwing error at @res and if i remove @ then it saying unknown column 'res'

Answer (score 1):

Please rechange Query as

`"INSERT INTO table_name(field1, field2, field3, field4......) SELECT field1, field2, @res := function_name(field3,'2012-01-01'), @res/field1..... from table_name2 group by field1, field2;`

which is same as that of you specified. that is correct I have checked like this

```
mysql> select ( @point := sum(points)), @point/12  from votes;
+--------------------------+-------------+
| ( @point := sum(points)) | @point/12   |
+--------------------------+-------------+
|                       20 | 1.000000000 |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```